# Spreadsheet hide formula result

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following formula in cell `D255`.

`=$C$3+(D255*$C$2)`

I wish to copy this down to `D1000`, but do not want to show the result until data is entered into the cells between `D255 and D1000` inclusive.

Comment: What does this have to do with Windows 10?

Comment: It sounds like you have a circular reference (a formula in D255 that uses itself in a calculation).

Comment: I'm removing Windows 10 for you @Ramhound upon further approval.

Comment: I would rather the author just clarify their question.

Comment: Either way, it'll get done.  No worries.  :)

Comment: Putting this question on hold for `unclear` the day _after_ it was given an answer that was also accepted seems a bit silly and capricious. It was perfectly clear to me _and_ the other person who answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=IF(D255>0,$c$3+(D255*$c$2),"-")`

You can replace `"-"` with whatever you want to appear when the field is blank. However, as fixer1234 pointed out in the comments, if you put that formula in cell *D255*, you will have a circular reference, and Excel isn't fond of those. If you put this formula in cell *E255*, and the values you want to calculate in *D255*, all will be good.

Comment: thank you for your time to answer my question,this is great for someone like me who is new to this it works I replaced "-" with "0" as the next cell adds up so it also shows 0 the only question now is when I copy the  formula down the  grid lines fade out? you can see them but are very faint? again thanks,

Comment: Glad you found it helpful - clicking the up arrow and check mark next to the answer are good ways of showing that, too. The _StackExchange way_ is to not include a new question in the answer section, so for your grid lines issue, I would suggest a new question with images showing what's happening. If, however, it's just the right edge line, it may be that your data is wider than the column, so Excel is hiding the right edge line allowing the text to overlap into the next cell - try making your column wider.

Comment: The "fading" cell borders could also be because you _had_ a border defined around your destination cells, but _not_ around your source. If that's the case, the source cell border would have copied over the destination borders when you copy pastad your cell with the new formula.

Comment: All sorted thanks very much clicked borders all came back .

Answer (score 0):

So if no data is in D255 you wish to show an empty cell.  Calculating on the same cell that you wish to show data in isn't possible since it would be circular referencing.  To avoid circular logic you simply put the data you wish to calculate with in a column next to the other column.  This formula would be in D255 and the data that it would check against would be next to the formula in E255.  Of  course you can hide the column if the data can't be shown.

> =if (E255="","",$C$3+(E255*$C$2)

Now D255 will not show anything unless data is put into it.  I'm assuming of course c2 and c3 have been set.  And again if you didn't want the data to show in E255 you can always hide the column.  Another way of handling this might be to put the data you are calculating against on another sheet.

Comment: This would work, except D255 is in the formula, so it's circular. Which is what we are trying to clarify with the user.